# Emgu Canny very slow. What to do?

Tags: emgucv

I'm having a very difficult problem with EMGU 3.0 and canny edge.

I am trying to use the Canny method to detect edges, but it becomes so slow that it is unusable.

Everything works well *and real-time* without the Canny line (which is commented out below), but then, if I un-comment the "CvInvoke.Canny...". line basically the whole program comes to a brutal stop!!! I have the latest emgu 3.0 installed and properly referenced with dll's and cvextern.dll.

There are **no errors** when building solution.

FYI i'm capturing images from a microscope camera (using toupcam.dll) which works perfectly fine.

Here is the code snippet of the problem. Again, this works perfectly ***until*** I un-comment the CvInvoke.Canny line below. Then, it basically stops... 
s
What the heck??

```
        private void OnEventImage()
    {
        if (bmp_ != null)
        {
            BitmapData bmpdata = bmp_.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp_.Width, bmp_.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp_.PixelFormat);

            uint nWidth = 0, nHeight = 0;
            toupcam_.PullImage(bmpdata.Scan0, 24, out nWidth, out nHeight);

            bmp_.UnlockBits(bmpdata);

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp_;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();

            Image<Bgr, Byte> frameimg = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmp_);
            iboxEdge.Image = frameimg;
            iboxEdge.Invalidate();

            Image<Gray, Byte> grayimg = new Image<Gray, byte>(frameimg.Bitmap);
            Mat edgeimg = grayimg.Mat;

            //CvInvoke.Canny(edgeimg, edgeimg, 100, 200, 3, false);

            iboxCanny.Image = edgeimg;
            iboxCanny.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yea no answer. I really hoped for a reply. still haven't solved this. if do, will post any solution.